# Jenkinsfile | Multibranch Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

Below is my pipeline:-

```
#!groovy
String version
String awsRegion = "us-east-1"
String appName = "abcde"
String dockerFilePath = "."
def featureEnv = env.BRANCH_NAME != 'master'
String branchName = env.BRANCH_NAME
String env = (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') ? 'release' : 'develop'
String ecrRepo = featureEnv ? "123456789012.dkr.ecr.${awsRegion}.amazonaws.com/abcde_${env}" : "987654321098.dkr.ecr.${awsRegion}.amazonaws.com/abcde_master"
String terraformPath = "terraform/dev"
println "Feature Environment=${featureEnv}"

pipeline {
    agent none
    options {
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr: '30'))
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        timeout(time: 6, unit: 'HOURS')
        ansiColor('xterm')
    }

    stages {
        stage('version build'){
          agent { label 'linux' }
          steps {
            script {
                    version = VersionNumber(
                        versionNumberString: '1.0.${BUILD_NUMBER, X}',
                        skipFailedBuilds:    false)
                    currentBuild.displayName = version
                    println "Pipeline Version='${version}'"
              }
        }
    }
        
        stage('Build') {
            when {
                anyOf { branch 'develop'; branch 'release' }
            }
            agent { label 'linux' }
            steps {
                checkout scm
                unstash name: "${appName}-docker"
                dir(dockerFilePath) {
                     sh("""
                        while IFS= read -r line; do
                            build_args+=" --build-arg \$line"
                        done < "env_vars.txt"
                        #echo \$build_args
                        docker build -t ${ecrRepo}:${version} \$build_args --no-cache=true .
                        eval \$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region ${awsRegion})
                        docker push ${ecrRepo}:${version}
                        docker rmi ${ecrRepo}:${version}
                     """)
               }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am using Multibranch pipelines to execute Jenkins job but for branch `release`, Its by default taking `develop` branch i am attaching docker build and docker push outputs of Jenkins instead release ECR repo. Please suggest.

Jenkins Output:-

```
+ docker build -t 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abcde_develop:1.0.2 --build-arg HOST=0.0.0.0 --build-arg PORT=8080 --build-arg DOMAIN=abcde --build-arg MSAL_CLIENT_ID=1234567-bd11-4d2e-add5-d78f5e59e976 --build-arg
+ docker push 123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/abcde_develop:1.0.2
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you can use for test purpose this version

```
when {
                expression { BRANCH_NAME ==~ /(develop|release)/ }
}
```